# how to loop each item from text file in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a text file which contains list of four address. see the screenshot below:

[image]

Within my selenium scraper I pass each address as keys. `addresselements.send_keys(lines)`. When running the selenium driver it's only taking the first address from my text file and quite the browser.

here is summary of my full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver =  webdriver.Chrome
url ="my terget url"
driver.get(url) 
addressElement = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#search-input-adresse')
        
#impoting address from text file
f = open('address.txt')
lines = f.readline()
        
for addresselements in addressElement:
    addresselements.send_keys(lines) #enter your address 
    addresselements.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

How I loop all address one by one. I also tried this code but didn't work

```
f = open('address.txt')
lines = f.readline()
for line in f:        
    for addresselements in addressElement:
         addresselements.send_keys(lines) #enter your address 
         addresselements.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: _I also tried this code but didn't work_ What do you mean, what happens? Have you done any debugging? Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: getting "urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:"

Comment: That's important information, please include the entire error output in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readline()` only reads one line, you need to use `readlines()` if you want to get all the data from your file.

```
with open('address.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        for addresselements in addressElement:
             addresselements.send_keys(line) #enter your address 
             addresselements.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: Hi PacketLoss. not working still  now getting the same error  "urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError"

Comment: Then your issue is not even listed in your question. Your question quite specifically states you are only getting one address, which is caused by the `readline()` problem. `MaxRetryError` is not even related to the address problem. https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.exceptions.html#urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError

Comment: getting the error ""urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError" after using your code but in my code there is no error .just taking  the first address from the text file and quit the browser

Comment: Then there must be a further issue into how you are calling the url etc. If you can provide your target url, i can test the code against the same endpoint to see why you're encountering the error.

Comment: PacketLoss your code passing all four address at a time instead of passing one by one that the reason I am getting error from your code

Comment: Recreating your text file, the above code loops over all lines, processing one line at a time. It should not return all lines in one iteration. Please edit your question to show this issue.

Comment: I find out the solution I just put `addresselements.send_keys(line.strip())` instead of   `addresselements.send_keys(line)`

Comment: Your file must have had `\n` at the end of each line. Glad it works!